# MySQL joined WHERE IN combined with NOT IN (categories)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a whitelist and a blacklist of category UIDs.

I am trying to tell MySQL that

- i want all pages that have at least "57", but
- that i don't want any pages that ALSO have "206".

Usually i would say "IN(57)" excludes everything else, like 206, but certain pages have both (57 and 206) so it's true either way. 
The unwanted 206 page is still included.

Here's the Query:

```
SELECT pages.uid, pages.title
FROM pages 
LEFT JOIN sys_category_record_mm AS cats ON (pages.uid = cats.uid_foreign AND cats.tablenames="pages" AND cats.fieldname="categories") 
WHERE pages.hidden=0 AND pages.deleted=0 
AND cats.uid_local IN (57) 
AND cats.uid_local NOT IN (206) 
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN pages.starttime > 0 THEN pages.starttime ELSE pages.crdate END) DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Here is a **DB Fiddle** for this Problem:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fxGQbBVZHb8aJDJ4eiTUW1/0

I am out of ideas. Any help/hint would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this sort of logic simplest with `group by` and `having`:

```
select c.uid_foreign
from sys_category_record_mm c
where c.tablenames = 'pages' AND c.fieldname = 'categories' 
group by c.uid_foreign
having sum(c.uid_local in (57)) > 0 and
       sum(c.uid_local in (206)) = 0;
```

You can join back to your pages to get additional information.

Comment: I used it as subquery: WHERE pages.uid IN( select c... ) and it looks like it works. Anything to look out for when doing so? Thanks.

Comment: @m3nt0r . . . That should actually be fine.